# null values assigning while reading the data from excel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng, testng-dataprovider

1)in excel sheet we give 4rows (with header5) am able to execute but 4th row is taking as null

2)if am giving only 1 row (with header2) am getting error as testOnboardProvider (null, null, null, null, null, null), java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys to send should be a not null CharSequence

```java
public class OnboardProvider extends ProjectSpecificMethods {
  @Test(dataProvider = "sendData")
  public void testOnboardProvider(String ProviderName, String Email, String contactperson, String phno, String address, String pincode) throws InterruptedException {

    new LoginPage()
      .enterUsername("manojgumma221@gmail.com")
      .enterPassword("9491233055")
      .clickLogin()
      .clickUserManagement()
      .clickProviderUser()
      .clickOnAddNewProvider()
      .enterName(ProviderName)
      .enterEmail(Email)
      .enterContactPerson(contactperson)
      .enterContactNumber(phno)
      .enterAddress(address)
      .selectCountry()
      .selectState()
      .SelectCity()
      .enterZipCode(pincode)
      .clickOnboard()
      .verifyProverName();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

  }

  public class ReadExcel {

    public String[][] readExcel() throws IOException {
      XSSFWorkbook wBWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook("./Data/auto.xlsx");
      XSSFSheet wSheet = wBWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
      int rows = wSheet.getLastRowNum();
      System.out.println("No of rows" + rows + "are:");
      int cells = wSheet.getRow(rows).getLastCellNum();
      System.out.println(cells);
      String[][] data = new String[rows][cells];
      for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < cells; j++) {
          String value = wSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
          System.out.println(value);
          data[i - 1][j] = value;
        }
      }
      wBWorkbook.close();
      return data;

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop starts at i=1, which is correct since we don't want to include the headers; but ends at 4 since it is < 5. And when i=5 it gets out of the for loop and you never get the data for row 5.

Following should fix your problem:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < cells; j++) {
          String value = wSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
          System.out.println(value);
          data[i - 1][j] = value;
        }
      }
```

Also, as a side tip. Sometimes I had similar issue because of the mere fact that I had entered and deleted some info in excel. Deleting the row fully has fixed my problem. Seems like if you only delete the content of the cell doesn't help.

Comment: You should probably check that both the Row and Cell are defined and not null - [Sheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) returns null if there's no row in the file